# how to use image from dll

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

i have a customized grid view.
it has a property "Theme".
this property has some item (enum) that change apperacne of my gridview such as hedar background image,rowstyle,rowcolor,etc... .
this property work fine.but i must add a folder (contained image) to show background image of header.
i must prepare this folder for users (that use my gridview in their website) .
i want just users(programmers) add my dll(gridview) and change theme of my grid without any additional work.
if you see in my code i must add backgroundimage style refrencde by a floder in web site(ThemeResource/HeaderSoftGamer.png).and naturally users(programmers) must copy this folder of page that use my gridview

```
 public class MTGridView : GridView
{
    public enum ThemeCollection { HardBlue, Black, Girly , Sky , Samta };
    private ThemeCollection currentTheme;
    public ThemeCollection Theme
    {
        get
        {
            return currentTheme;
        }
        set
        {
            currentTheme = value;
        }

    }
     public MTGridView()
    {
          this.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(MTGridView_RowCreated);
    }
     void MTGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (Theme)
        {
            case ThemeCollection.Sky:
                {

                    switch (e.Row.RowType)
                    {
                        case DataControlRowType.Header:
                            e.Row.Style.Add("background-color", "blue");
                            e.Row.Style.Add("font-family", "Tahoma");
                            e.Row.Style.Add("font-size", hs.ToString());
                            e.Row.Style.Add("color", "Black");
                            e.Row.Style.Add("background-image", "url(ThemeResource/HeaderSoftGamer.png)");
                         break;
                     }
                   }
              }
     }}
```

thank all

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep your images on your server and use them from your code or give the complete image folder and ask them to include it with their project. I don't see a workaround for this..